# У меня есть функция что б вернуть самое длинное слово, но я не понимаю почему переменной word присвоили значение null

Tags: javascript

У меня есть функция что б вернуть самое длинное слово, но я не понимаю почему переменной word присвоили значение null

```
 function longestWord(string) {
    let str = string.split(" ");
    let longest = 0;
    let word = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            longest = str[i].length;
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: Может была передана пустая строка `"" | " "`, тогда это нормальное поведение.

Comment: Кто-то лепит null везде абсолютно, поэтому для кого-то это норма. Но в целом - нет

Answer (score -2):

Чтобы использовать оператор `??` при пустой строке или передаче в функцию/метод принимающую `String|null`

```js
function longestWordWithNull(string) {
    let str = string.split(" ");
    let longest = 0;
    let word = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            longest = str[i].length;
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    return word;
}
function longestWord(string) {
    let str = string.split(" ");
    let longest = 0;
    let word = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            longest = str[i].length;
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    return word;
}

console.log(`null: `,longestWordWithNull('') ?? 'empty')
console.log(`empty string: `,longestWord('') ?? 'empty')
```

Comment: Вопрос вроде бы не в том, как что-то сделать (правильно или не правильно), а в том, почему там word инициализирован как null

Comment: Где я писал, как правильно или нет? `word` инициирован как `null` чтоб  использовать оператор `??` при пустой строке или передаче в функцию/метод принимающую `String|null`.

Comment: Функция, которая должна возвращать самое длинное слово в строке будет принимать null? О_о  Серьёзно?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Где я писал, что она будет принимать `null`?

Comment: Перечитай свой сообщение ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "передаче в функцию/метод принимающую" - где здесь о "принимать `null`"?